# Is there a way to see a particular organization's 501(c)(3) application?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-profit

For example let's say I wanted to see how the Free Software Foundation or the GNOME Foundation applied. Are those records accessible by the public?

Comment: Some organizations do publish these documents on the web, e.g. https://static.mozilla.com/foundation/documents/mf-irs-501c3-application.pdf

Comment: Also, the organization itself is required to provide a copy of its application if you make a request in writing, but may require that you pay reasonable copying and postage costs first. https://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Public-Disclosure-and-Availability-of-Exempt-Organizations-Returns-and-Applications:-Disclosures-Required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can! Check out the [IRS website.](https://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Exempt-Organizations-Public-Disclosure-Obtaining-Copies-of-Documents-from-IRS)

> IF you want...
>
> A copy of an exemption application...
>
> THEN file Form 4506-A with...
>
> Internal Revenue Service 
>   Attn: Correspondence Unit
>
> You may also purchase copies of scanned Forms 990, 990-EZ for IRC section 501(c)(3) organizations, Form 990-T (IRC section 501(c)(3) organizations filed after August 17, 2006)  and all 990-PF returns on DVD from the Ogden Submission Processing Center.